# Excel cant cope with large data set - need to lookup

Tags: excel, vba, database, excel-formula

So I have a data set of about 150k lookup references. I am trying to see if at any point these appear in my other dataset of around 4 Million.

If so, return true. Anything that returns false will be deleted from our crm.

I am currently just trying lookups of the 150k against 200k at a time but it still keeps crashing...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try using Power Query. Minimise your column count, and sort your index columns.

Comment: Use another program: we used SAS to process large amounts of data - disadvantage is that the learning curve is steep ... there are both advantages and disadvantages..

Comment: @Olly Hey thanks for the response, would reducing column count matter if the formula is only referencing those 200k rows?

Comment: @CillianKane If you're loading tables to Power Query, and you're only interested in matching values between two lists, then there's no need to load all the other columns into your query tables.

Comment: @CillianKane - That's a pretty vague problem description. Is this ***only*** a dataset or is this a giant workbook full of formulas? If so, is there any chance the formulas aren't planned as efficiently as they could be?  200k "typical" records shouldn't be an issue -- how much data/how many fields are in each record? ***How*** are you doing this lookup? Please share your formula/code.

Comment: What formula are you actually using to look up? match?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide more information. Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and also check out "[ask]", as well as the tips here about posting a **[mcve]**  Also @CillianKane *Welcome to Stack Overflow!*  :-)

Comment: @jamheadart Hi, =countif($A$1:$A$200000,G1)>0 would be an example of what I am currently using.

Comment: @ashleedawg  It is literally just lookup references, eg. jkl0254, 150,000 of those vs 5,000,000 of codes just like that.

Comment: @CillianKane -That's you're only formula?  So you're only returning `TRUE`/`FALSE`? And you have exactly 200k rows?

Comment: @ashleedawg My thinking was if I do it for only 200k rows at a time, excel would be able to handle it. I have about 15 columns, each with 200k in it. I was just going to do them one at a time, but it still crashes - or takes a ridiculous amount of time. And yes returning True/False

Comment: For a start, have you tried MATCH? e.g. `=MATCH(G1,$A$1:$A$200000,0)` - I think it might be faster since it won't have to count all instances - it'll return a number instead of `true` and `#N/A` instead of `false`

Comment: @jamheadart Thanks for the continued help Jamheadart.

The thing is the chance of it being within the 200k are slim so the match formula will still have to check every cell, only when it returns true (which is unlikely) will it save time, I have just tried it and although an improvement its not a viable alternative! But thank you all the same!

Comment: @CillianKane - what is the end goal?  Do you just need to know if the ID# exists in the data?  If so why are you counting every row (or using a counting function at all instead of a lookup function)?  It would be very helpful if your question included an **sample of your data** and an example of your *end-goal*.  Surely you're not finished once you get a list of `TRUE`/`FALSE`? (Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).)  There's a lot of time being wasted by not including all relevant information in this question.

Comment: @ashleedawg Indeed Ashleedawg I just need to know if it exists, basically taken the lookup references from companies on our crm and need to compare them to a GDPR Compliant List. Once I have a list of True/False I will be done - apart from reimporting to our crm and deleting all Falses!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any code here, I could provide one example from a code I recentrly wrote. Maybe you can get an idea how to handle your problem.

> ```
>         Dim rFoundCell As Range                                               
>         Dim the_string As String
>
>         Set xFoundCell = Sheets("Database").Range("B1:B100000").Find(Userform.Something, 
>         LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
>         Sheets("ED").Range("B2") = xFoundCell.Address                                       
>         the_string = Sheets("ED").Range("B2")                                               
>         the_string = Replace(the_string, "B", "")                                           
>         the_string = Replace(the_string, "$", "")                                           
>         Sheets("ED").Range("B2") = the_string
> ```

This is a part of my code which is used to get the adress of my cell.
You could customize something like this in a loop and lookup all your cells.

Hope this can help you
Best regards